# scheduling a java program

Tags: java, windows, service, scheduling

I have a working java program, which takes set of files in a folder that user inputs and process them.

Now users don't require their intervention. They want the program to run every 30 min and process the files from a pre-determined path.

When I googled it I got to know I should use schedulers. So should we go for OS specific scheduler or Java scheduler?
And also how to use the one that is recommended?

Also on system restart the process should start automatically.

Thanks in advance.
Harsha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the system is more or less always up, use a Java scheduler (google how to use Executor/TimerTask). If you need the process to start automatically on system restart, you need to go the OS specific route.

For windows, schedule a service to run your java program every 30 mins (see http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task for an example). You basically need to run "java -cp {some classpath} {your program}"

For Unix-based systems, set up a cron job that calls your java program every 30 mins.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way is to use `TimerTask`. In my example your operation will run every 30 min.

```
public class Schedular extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your operation
    }

    public void start() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 5 *  1000 , 60 * 30 * 1000);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Schedular schedular = new Schedular();
        schedular.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1570824 After the system reboot, you need to run again your program. If you would like to start automatically after system reboot, you must add your program as `system service` of Operation System.

Comment: So if I want to go in java way of scheduling we should use java timertask and also add it as windows service to start it automatically on restart. Correct?

Comment: Yes, If you use window, your program must be window service.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to deal with this might be to create a cron job. The benefit is its simplicity and 'standardization' ie. people know where to look for recurring jobs. The downside is you've created another dependency for your program to run properly. If you do create a cron entry, remember your java program should be designed in a stateless manner.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: I like your point of not creating dependency. But will work on windows machine?

Comment: I believe the entire Windows family have 'Task Scheduler' which works pretty much the same way as cron, with an easy to use user interface.